# Spring MVC Portlet - Issue with Ajax JQuery html replace

Tags: jquery, ajax, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

first - the div tag doesn't get replaced with content from the controller.
second - even if I replaced with some static html data which I comment out in side the js function it only displays on top of html but not replacing the table data. any idea what am I doing wrong here?

### JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxRem(val) {
    var url = '<portlet:resourceURL id="ajaxRem"/>';
    var posting = $.post( url, { attachmentID: val } );  
  posting.done(function( data ) {  
    //$("#ajaxMarkup").html("<table><tr><td><b>Hello world!</b></td></tr></table>");
    $("#ajaxMarkup").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<portlet:actionURL var="sendMessageURL"> <portlet:param name="action" value="send"></portlet:param> </portlet:actionURL>
<form:form method="post" id="replyMessageForm" commandName="messageForm" action="${sendMessageURL}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <portlet:defineObjects /> <br />
    <c:forEach items="${messageForm.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="status">
    <DIV id="ajaxMarkup">
        <TABLE cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="BigPadTable" id="msgTableDisplay" border="0" jsid="msgTableDisplay">                                          
            <c:forEach items="${message.attachmentList}" var="attachment" varStatus="count">                                            
            <c:set value="${attachment.attachmentID}" var="attachmentID"></c:set>                                           
            <%                                          
            Integer msgIdInt = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("attachmentID");
            String attachID = msgIdInt.toString();                                          
            %>                                          
            <TR name="DataContainer">
                <TD name="DocSize_ColumnData" valign="top"
                    class="tableCell"><SPAN name="DocSize"
                    class="outputData"><c:out value="${attachment.attachmentSize}"/></SPAN>
                </TD>                                               
                <TD id="remAttach" name="Document_PageAutoDelete_ColumnData"
                    valign="top" class="tableCell"><p id="demo" onclick="javascript:ajaxRem(<%=attachID%>);"><u>[Remove]</u></p>
                </TD>                                               
            </TR>                                           
            </c:forEach>                                                                                
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Controller:

```
@Controller("sendMessageController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@SessionAttributes(types = MessageForm.class)
public class SendMessageController implements HandlerExceptionResolver{ 
    @ResourceMapping("ajaxRem")
    public void ajaxRem(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, Map<String, Object> model,@Valid @ModelAttribute("messageForm") MessageForm messageForm, BindingResult result,@RequestParam(required=false, value="attachmentID") String attachmentID) throws Exception {               
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(request);
        PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(false);      
        String attID = request.getParameter("attachmentID");
        ...logic to remove a record goes here...        
        model.put("messageForm", messageForm);  
        return new ModelAndView("fileList", model);     
    }   
}
```

### fileList.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>  
    <portlet:defineObjects /> <br />
    <c:forEach items="${messageForm.messageList}" var="message" varStatus="status">

        <TABLE cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="BigPadTable" id="msgTableDisplay" border="0" jsid="msgTableDisplay">                                          
            <c:forEach items="${message.attachmentList}" var="attachment" varStatus="count">                                            
            <c:set value="${attachment.attachmentID}" var="attachmentID"></c:set>                                           
            <%                                          
            Integer msgIdInt = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("attachmentID");
            String attachID = msgIdInt.toString();                                          
            %>                                          
            <TR name="DataContainer">
                <TD name="DocSize_ColumnData" valign="top"
                    class="tableCell"><SPAN name="DocSize"
                    class="outputData"><c:out value="${attachment.attachmentSize}"/></SPAN>
                </TD>                                               
                <TD id="remAttach" name="Document_PageAutoDelete_ColumnData"
                    valign="top" class="tableCell"><p id="demo" onclick="javascript:ajaxRem(<%=attachID%>);"><u>[Remove]</u></p>
                </TD>                                               
            </TR>                                           
            </c:forEach>            
        </TABLE>
     </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to get rid of `<html>`,`<head>`,`<body>` tags from your jsp as in any portlet project it should come from theme not from portlet.

if still problem persist then try to debug from firebug if you are using firefox or developers tool in case of chrome.Just give a try removing everything from `<div>` to understand whether actually ts updating html or not.

```
  $("#ajaxMarkup").html("");
```